# I need to explore the sysml metamode, as XMI file

Tags: eclipse, emf, metamodel, xmi, sysml

I need to explore the Metamodel of SysMl, I have tried with make new emf project and add the following xmi file http://www.omg.org/spec/SysML/20120401/ISO-80000-1-SysML.xmi.

But I could not open it using emf editor, because of missed package, for example in this file the following namespaces is needed

```
<xmi:XMI xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/spec/XMI/20110701"
     xmlns:mofext="http://www.omg.org/spec/MOF/20110701"
     xmlns:uml="http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20110701"
     xmlns:sysml="http://www.omg.org/spec/SysML/20120322/SysML">
```

Have you an idea how I can import this namespaces, or how I can explore SysMl metamodel?

I have installed Papyros in Eclipse